# Blender rig not working correctly. What do I do?

Tags: modifiers, rigging, bones

**I apologize if I've made any mistakes prior to encountering this problem, I'm still new to rigging.**

Alright, so I made a model and rigged it, but every time i rotate/grab a bone, the mesh doesn't follow correctly.

[image: location error]
[image: rotation error]

Here's the blend file: http://www.mediafire.com/download/ny2yon0s53ibpyf/wonkyrig.blend

I've tried asking on other sites, but I've had no luck. I would really appreciate the help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is your model as one object ?

Comment: @IgorTatarnikov Yes, the only 2 objects are the model and the armature.